# query accessing repository not returning data

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository

Symfony / Doctrine - Repository not returning data.

I have successfully retrieved data from another entity/repository previously, but can't seem to fetch data from this particular repository. I have cleared cache in console and I have registered the repository with the entity class (with annotation).

Testing the DQL as SQL returns results as expected, meaning parameters passed into query will return results I desire through SQL query, just not DQL query.

The one difference between the route that is accessing this repository in comparison to past successful repository queries is the "parameter bag" is being passed through request "attributes" in this repository and in the successful previous repository queries the query parameters were passed through request "query - Parameter Bag" in the request. I am not sure it is even part of the repository query problem however.

The Controller

```
/**
 * Open the modal dialog for selecting strip width
 * @Route("/select/{materialId}/{gaugeId}/{rangeUpper}/{rangeLower}", defaults={"materialId" = 0, "gaugeId" = 0, "rangeUpper" = 0, "rangeLower" = 0}, name="material-stock_selectWidth")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function selectStripWidthAction (Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $materialStocks = $em->getRepository('UniflyteBundle:MaterialStock')->findAllByParams($request);



    return $this->render('materialstock/dialog/select.html.twig', [
        'MaterialStock' => $materialStocks,
    ]);
}
```

The Repository

```
public function findAllByParams (Request $request)
{

    $criteria = $request->query->get('uniflytebundle_material-stock_selectWidth');

    $criteria = ($request->get('materialId') == 0 ? [] : ['materialId' => $request->get('materialId')]);
    $criteria = array_merge(($request->get('gaugeId') == 0 ? [] : ['gaugeId' => $request->get('gaugeId')]), $criteria);
    $criteria = array_merge(($request->get('rangeUpper') == 0 ? [] : ['rangeUpper' => $request->get('rangeUpper')]), $criteria);
    $criteria = array_merge(($request->get('rangeLower') == 0 ? [] : ['rangeLower' => $request->get('rangeLower')]), $criteria);
    $criteria = array_filter($criteria);

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('ms');

    if (!empty($criteria)) {
        if (!empty($criteria['materialId']) && !empty($criteria['gaugeId']) && !empty($criteria['rangeUpper']) && !empty($criteria['rangeLower'])) {
            $query
              ->where('ms.material = :materialId')
              ->andWhere('ms.gauge = :gaugeId')
              ->andWhere('ms.widthDecimal <= :upperIdentifier')
              ->andWhere('ms.widthDecimal >= :lowerIdentifier')
              ->setParameter('materialId', $criteria['materialId'])
              ->setParameter('gaugeId', $criteria['gaugeId'])
              ->setParameter('upperIdentifier', $criteria['rangeUpper'])
              ->setParameter('lowerIdentifier', $criteria['rangeLower'])
            ;
        }
    }
    return $query->orderBy('ms.widthDecimal', 'DESC');
}
```

Displaying results

```
<select>
    {% for MaterialStock in MaterialStock %}
        <option>{{ MaterialStock.widthDecimal }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

A dump() from the controller showing queryBuilder.

```
MaterialStockController.php on line 139:
array:1 [▼
"materialStocks" => QueryBuilder {#613 ▼
-_em: EntityManager {#757 …11}
-_dqlParts: array:9 [▼
  "distinct" => false
  "select" => array:1 [▶]
  "from" => array:1 [▶]
  "join" => []
  "set" => []
  "where" => Andx {#642 ▼
    #separator: " AND "
    #allowedClasses: array:4 [▶]
    #preSeparator: "("
    #postSeparator: ")"
    #parts: array:4 [▼
      0 => "ms.material = :materialId"
      1 => "ms.gauge = :gaugeId"
      2 => "ms.widthDecimal <= :upperIdentifier"
      3 => "ms.widthDecimal >= :lowerIdentifier"
    ]
  }
  "groupBy" => []
  "having" => null
  "orderBy" => array:1 [▶]
]
-_type: 0
-_state: 0
-_dql: null
-parameters: ArrayCollection {#646 ▼
  -elements: array:4 [▼
    0 => Parameter {#645 ▼
      -name: "materialId"
      -value: "1"
      -type: 2
    }
    1 => Parameter {#644 ▼
      -name: "gaugeId"
      -value: "7"
      -type: 2
    }
    2 => Parameter {#648 ▼
      -name: "upperIdentifier"
      -value: "3.75"
      -type: 2
    }
    3 => Parameter {#643 ▼
      -name: "lowerIdentifier"
      -value: "3.5"
      -type: 2
    }
  ]
}
-_firstResult: null
-_maxResults: null
-joinRootAliases: []
#cacheable: false
#cacheRegion: null
#cacheMode: null
#lifetime: 0
```

}
]

Registering Repository in Entity Class

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UniflyteBundle\Repository\MaterialStockRepository")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I appreciate any time/energy/thought/suggestions invested on this challenge. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you mind dumping your DQL, for reference? (And the working SQL that you extrapolated from it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the query, but you did not get result.

`findAllByParams` method should look like that:

```
public function findAllByParams ($arguments)
{
  // query building goes here
  // ...
  $query->orderBy('ms.widthDecimal', 'DESC');
  return $query->getQuery()->getResult()
}
```

Don't pass `Request` to your repository method, get the parameters(and validate them) on the outside, for example, in controller.

Answer (score 2):

I think you miss this : `->getQuery()->getResult()` (this return the data of the querybuilder ) in the return of `findAllByParams` function (on the query builder). Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes that is what it was.  I appreciate you sharing knowledge. Thank you. The other repository query returned results without ->getQuery()->getResult().